# Using lookup plugin to check SHA512 password hash

Tags: ansible, lookup

In my Ansible git repo, I have a var file with contents like this

```
vault_users:
  alex:
    password: $6$PwhqORmvn$tXctAkh9RLs60ZFhn9Cxz/eLZEx1UhQkbDIoM6xWsk7M18TApDd9/b8CHJnEiaiQE2YJ8mqu6kvsGuImDt4dy/
  danny:
    password: $6$PwhqORmvn$tXctAkh9RLs60ZFhn9Cxz/eLZEx1UhQkbDIoM6xWsk7M18TApDd9/b8CHJnEiaiQE2YJ8mqu6kvsGuImDt4dy/
  gary:
    password: $6$PwhqORmvn$tXctAkh9RLs60ZFhn9Cxz/eLZEx1UhQkbDIoM6xWsk7M18TApDd9/b8CHJnEiaiQE2YJ8mqu6kvsGuImDt4dy/
```

Now, I want to check if the password hashes from this var file matches the ones from the `/etc/shadow` file on a remote server. I know it is possible to mix Ansible and a bash/python script to get what I want. I would like to know if it is possible to do this using pure Ansible playbooks only (no bash/python scripts) using the lookup plugin or some other Ansible feature.

Comment: I know I can run the playbook in check mode but it would be nice if Ansible could tell me which user's password changed which will save me from scrolling hundreds of line to find out what actually changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use line in file to check if line has changed, register result and store it in another variable if lineinfile module returned "changed".

Unfortunately, due to [this bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13366)  you can't simply use with_items and backrefs in lineinfile module to check if strings are valid, so i used a little include hack.

So we have a playbook called `playbook.yml` and task called `checkpasswords.yml`, let's explain each of them.

#### playbook.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    # execute checkpasswords.yml for each user in vault_users dict 
    # and pass each user (or item) as {{ user }} variable to included task
    - include: checkpasswords.yml user="{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ vault_users }}"
    - debug: msg="{{ changed_users|default([]) }}"
```

#### checkpasswords.yml

```
- name: check for user and hash
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/shadow
    regexp: '{{ user }}:([^:]+):(.*)'
    # replace sting with user:hashed_password:everything_that_remains
    line: '{{ user }}:{{ vault_users[user].password }}:\2'
    state: present
    backrefs: yes
  register: u

- name: changed users
  set_fact:
    # set changed_users list to [] if not present and add [user] element
    # when user password has changed
    changed_users: "{{ changed_users|default([]) + [user] }}"
  when: u.changed
```

#### hashvars.yml

```
vault_users:
  root:
    password: "nothing to see here"
  my_user:
    password: "nothing here"
```

I included variables to `hashvars.yml` file and changed hashes for my_user and root inside it. So the result of executing this playbook will be something like output below, **don't forget --check!**

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e @hashvars.yml --check

   PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

   TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
   ok: [localhost]

   TASK [include] *****************************************************************
   included: /home/my_user/workspace/so/checkpasswords.yml for localhost
   included: /home/my_user/workspace/so/checkpasswords.yml for localhost

   TASK [check for user and hash] *************************************************
   changed: [localhost]

   TASK [changed users] ***********************************************************
   ok: [localhost]

   TASK [check for user and hash] *************************************************
   changed: [localhost]

   TASK [changed users] ***********************************************************
   ok: [localhost]

   TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
   ok: [localhost] => {
       "msg": [
           "my_user",
           "root"
       ]
   }

   PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
   localhost                  : ok=8    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer.